# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected 'ROWS'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run the below query from snowflake web UI, Here is the error message:

```
select ROWS from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."METERING_HISTORY";
```

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected 'ROWS'

When I do a

`select *` on the view, I am able to see the column 'ROWS'.

Answer (score 1):

put the column name rows in quote, as it is a reserved name (ANSI reserved) , any reason why the column is called ROWS ?

```
select "ROWS" from tst1;
```

Comment: "any reason why the column is called ROWS " - "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."METERING_HISTORY" is snowflake's internal view, 'indicates number of rows reclustered during the START_TIME and END_TIME window.'. Refer - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/metering_history.html#columns

Answer (score 0):

You have used ROWS which is a reserved keyword. You can use it when enclosed within quotes.

select "ROWS" from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."METERING_HISTORY";

You can refer to the below documentation for the reserved keywords list.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html#reserved-limited-keywords